# Cech to derived spectral sequence and sheafification

Tags: cohomology, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let X be a topological space, let $\mathcal{U} = \{U_i\}$ be a cover of X, and let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on X. If X is separated, each $U_i$ is affine, and $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent, then Cech cohomology computes derived functor cohomology; in general one only gets a spectral sequence
$$
H^p(\mathcal{U},\underline{H}^q(\mathcal{F})) \Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,\mathcal{F})
$$
where $\underline{H}^q(\mathcal{F})$ is the presheaf $U \mapsto H^q(U,\mathcal{F}|_U)$.

> **Question**: For q > 0, $\underline{H}^q(\mathcal{F})$ sheafifies to 0.

For a quasi-coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ this is clear because cohomology vanishes on affines. Is this really true in general? Brian Conrad states this in the introduction to his [notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/hypercover.pdf) on cohomological descent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, this is true in general.

It suffices to show the stalks vanish.  Pick $x \in X$ and take an injective resolution $0 \to {\cal F} \to I^0 \to \cdots$.  For any open $U$ containing $x$, we get a chain complex

$$0 \to I^0(U) \to I^1(U) \to \cdots$$

whose cohomology groups are $H^p(U,{\cal F}|_U)$.

Taking direct limits of these sections gives the chain complex

$$0 \to I^0_x \to I^1_x \to \cdots$$

of stalks, which has zero cohomology in positive degrees because the original complex was a resolution.  However, direct limits are exact and so we find

$$0 = {\rm colim}_{x \in U} H^p(U,{\cal F}|_U) = {\underline H}^p({\cal F})_x$$

as desired.

Generally, cohomology tells you the obstructions to patching local solutions into global solutions, and this says that locally those obstructions vanish.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another short proof: denote by $I,J$ the inclusion of sheaves on X into presheaves and sheafification respectively, then

$$
\underline{H}^p(\mathcal{F})\cong R^pI(\mathcal{F}).
$$

Since $J$ is exact,

$$
J\circ R^pI\cong R^p(J\circ I)
$$

and the later vanishes for $p>0$ as $J\circ I=id_{\mathfrak{Ab}(X)}$. So $\underline{H}^p(\mathcal{F})$ sheafifies to 0 for $p>0$.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but it relies a lot on understanding derived functors. The longer proof reveals more, so to say.

Comment: @Bombyxmori Depends on point of view. For me this proof reveals the conceptual reason behind the fact, which I could not really see in the longer one.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I agree. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that sheaves of abelian groups need to be locally acyclic.  Let me say what I mean in an example.  Take $X=\mathbb{C}^{2}$ with the classical (metric) topology.  Let $\mathcal{F} = \mathbb{Z}_{D}$ where $D=\mathbb{C}^{\times} \times \{0\}$.

Then for any arbitrarily small polydisk $U$ containing $(0,0)$ we have 
$H^{1}(U,\mathbb{Z}_{D}) = H^{1}(U \cap D, \mathbb{Z})$

is not vanishing.  It seems in this example that 
$\underline{H}^{1}(\mathcal{F})_{(0,0)}$ 
does not vanish.

Comment: Oh, I could have just used $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Just to clarify, the  assumptions of locally affine and quasi coherence are crucial.  The simple example of the push forward of the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ under the inclusion of $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ gives a sheaf of abelian groups which is not locally acyclic. 

Comment: Why should we have $H^{1}(U,\mathbb{Z}_{D}) = H^{1}(U \cap D, \mathbb{Z})$ ? If $X=\mathbb{C}$ and $D=\mathbb{C}^\times$, then $\mathbb{Z}_{D}$ fits into an exact sequence of sheaves on $\mathbb{C}$: $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{0}\rightarrow 0$, where the latter two are the constant sheaf resp. the skyscraper sheaf at $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$. The sequence remains exact, when computing global sections on any open disk $U$ containing $0$, and since $H^1(U,\mathbb{Z})=0$, the long exact sequence implies $H^1(U,\mathbb{Z}_D)=0$. Or not?

Comment: I just meant that if $i:\mathbb{C}^\times \to \mathbb{C}$ is the inclusion and $0 \in U \subset \mathbb{C}$ then $ H^1(U-\{0\}, \mathbb{Z})=H^1(U, i_*\mathbb{Z})$ using the Leray-Serre spectral sequence. This is $\mathbb{Z}$ for any open disk around $0$.

Comment: So $i_* \mathbb{Z}$ is not acyclic on the affine line, but of course it is not quasi-coherent.

Comment: So at least in the analytic setting it would not be true.